# Cookie behaviour / default cookie in 8.7 LTS vs. 9.5 LTS

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-8.7.x

It seems, that TYPO3 8.7 sets a default cookie in most cases.

[image: Cookie in TYPO3 8.7]

TYPO3 9.5 sets no cookie, at least if I don't set one myself.

Questions:

- Can I disable this cookie behaviour in 8.7 or is this cookie really needed?
- Is it right that this behaviour has changed in 9.5 and no cookie is set be default?

Comment: TYPO3 8.7 does **not** set a cookie - except, you (or an extension) requests one.
Please check the used extensions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just double checked. The session gets started by cooluri.

Comment: Hmm, I have not used cooluri since a long time, but I cant imagine why it needs cookies. Did you verify that by temporary uninstalling it?

Comment: @nito It does not really need a cookie, but definitely sets one. Verified by checking the code.